# How to run 32-bit win app using wine

Tags: homebrew, wine, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am using [brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/wine-stable) installation of WineHQ:

```
==> wine-stable: 7.0
https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS
/usr/local/Caskroom/wine-stable/7.0 (125B)
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/wine-stable.rb
==> Name
WineHQ-stable
==> Description
Compatibility layer to run Windows applications
==> Artifacts
Wine Stable.app (App)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/start/bin/appdb (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/start/bin/winehelp (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/msiexec (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/notepad (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/regedit (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/regsvr32 (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/wine (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/wine64 (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/wineboot (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/winecfg (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/wineconsole (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/winedbg (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/winefile (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/winemine (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/winepath (Binary)
/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/wineserver (Binary)
==> Caveats
wine-stable supports both 32-bit and 64-bit. It is compatible with an existing
32-bit wine prefix, but it will now default to 64-bit when you create a new
wine prefix. The architecture can be selected using the WINEARCH environment
variable which can be set to either win32 or win64.
```

I can run [IrfanView](https://irfanview.com) app like here:

```
wine64 /Users/msciwoj/Applications/Wineskin/iview460_x64/i_view64.exe 
00c4:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x257ae0, 0): stub
00c4:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010020, 0000000000257AE0): stub
0024:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x174690, 1): stub
0024:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000020050, 0000000000174690): stub
```

but I can't do same with it's 32-bit counterpart:

```
wine64 /Users/msciwoj/Applications/Wineskin/iview460/i_view32.exe 
00c4:err:wow:load_32bit_module failed to load dll c0000034
```

The thing is I am trying to run other software [Jpegcrop](https://jpegclub.org) which is another small (single .exe file) win 32-bit application which doesn't have its 64-bit equivalent and it's failing in identical way as 32-bit IrfanView above:

```
wine64 /Users/msciwoj/Applications/Wineskin/jpegcrop.exe 
00c4:err:wow:load_32bit_module failed to load dll c0000034
```

While it seems impossible to get the [Jpegcrop](https://jpegclub.org) 64-bit binary version from the developer and I am now forced to use only 64-bit apps (MacOS 10.15 Catalina) - is there any alternative way to run this app with Wine on my Mac?

Comment: Which version of macOS are you using?

Comment: @DavidAnderson: I mention that at the very end: "_I am now forced to use only 64-bit apps (MacOS 10.15 Catalina)_", but precisely it's `10.15.7`

Comment: I would suggest perhaps installing Windows are a virtual machine. The virtual machine software is free and Windows 10 can be downloaded for free. You can use Windows 10 without activation for free, but eventually you will need to buy a Windows 10 license (or delete the virtual machine and create a new one.)

Comment: Another option would be to install Mojave or older macOS in a virtual machine. This can be done at no cost. Install wine in this virtual machine and run your application.

Comment: thanks @DavidAnderson, those two options would definitely work but not on the table. Not going to buy Win license to run win freeware or bother with brand new macOS installation. Was looking to get an idea on `wine`'s capability here